# Class not found in an simple PHP Script

Tags: php

I have an Greeting.php with

```
<?php
    namespace sayinghello;
    class Greeting {
        public function getName() {
            return "Hello!";
        }
    }
```

and the calls into the sayinghello.php:

```
<?php
    $greeting = new Greeting();
    echo $greeting->getName();
```

When I tried to open the sayinghello.php with my Browser, the Class-Not-Found-Exception would be thrown

> ('Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'sayinghello\Greeting' not found
>   in C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\EfP\src\sayinghello\sayinghello.php:2
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\EfP\src\sayinghello\sayinghello.php on line
>   2

I use PHP with the XAMPP-Stack and the solutions of similar questions does not solved the problem...

Comment: Have you included that file?

Comment: did you included `Greeting.php` in `sayinghello.php` ?

Comment: Yeah with `include 'Greeting.php';`

Comment: `'Fatal error: .... on line 2` it means, you have not written `include 'Greeting.php';`

Comment: what is the `include_path` value? Have you modified that and is the `Greeting.php` script in the same directory as  `sayinghello.php`?

Comment: @RishiRaut I have tried the solution with the same error (than on line 3). My mistake is additionaly the missing `use sayingHello\Greeting;` statement.

Answer (score 2):

It now works. I needed to add two statements:

```
include 'Greeting.php';
```

AND

```
use sayinghello\Greeting;
```

Im programming with IntelliJ and only be familiar with Java. Thaugt that PHP will look automaticaly in the namespace for the classes.

Comment: use require_once, not include ;-)

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't automatic in Java either: you still need `import`, whether the statement is added by the IDE or by yourself. In any case, PHP allows some kind of automation if you use a class autoloader.

Comment: Yes, it is needed. But Java don't need to include the classfile. It's only one statement and not two. That was a little bit confusing.

Comment: Don't get that part wrong. `use` does not play any role in class loading, it's just a short-cut definition. You can omit it altogether and use the full name, as in `$greeting = new sayinghello\Greeting();`